# Equate a column vector and a row vector with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Supposing I have two Pandas series:

```
s1 = pandas.Series([1,2,3])
s2 = pandas.Series([3,1,2])
```

Is there a good way to equate them in a `column x row`-style? i.e. I want a DataFrame output that is the result of doing

```
1 == 3, 2 == 3, 3 == 3
1 == 1, 2 == 1, 3 == 1
1 == 2, 2 == 2, 3 == 2
```

With the expected output of

```
False False True
True  False False
False True  False
```

I understand that I could expand the two series out into dataframes in their own right and then equate those data frames, but then my peak memory usage will double. I could also loop through one series and equate each individual value to the other series, and then stack those output series together into a DataFrame, and I'll do that if I have to. But it feels like there should be a way to this.

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: Just updated with an explicit expected output--I had originally just included the "equivalent" matrix because I thought it would be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of broadcasting

```
res = s1[:,None] == s2[None,:]
```

Comment: Pablo C's solution wouldn't work for me because I actually need to be able to support different operations (not just equality) in an on-the-fly way. I profiled both this solution and BENY's solution and on even modestly sized datasets (1,000 elements in the series) this approach was about 8x faster.

Comment: I will note that I had to call `to_numpy()` on the series to avoid a deprecation warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `numpy.outer`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.outer(s1,1/s2) == 1, s1, s2) 

s2      3      1      2
s1                     
1   False   True  False
2   False  False   True
3    True  False  False
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do with `apply`

```
out = s1.apply(lambda x : s2==x)
Out[31]: 
       0      1      2
0  False   True  False
1  False  False   True
2   True  False  False
```